# Either or constraint in linear programming PULP

Tags: linear-programming, pulp

I am new to LP and also to using pulp. I'm trying to add an either/or constraint of the below form:

x ==0 or x >=35

I understand introducing a binary decision variable might help, but the model won't be a linear problem anymore. Are there other python packages I can use in that case?

Comment: Read [AIMMS Modeling Guide - Integer Programming Tricks](https://download.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/AIMMS3OM_IntegerProgrammingTricks.pdf) (7.1). You will need an upper-bound though,

Comment: Without knowing more about your application I can't think how you would do this without a binary variable. Why do you want your problem to be linear rather than a mixed integer linear program?